# updating qlabel after input waiting

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have seen some information posted about this, but everything seems to be with PyQt4 not PyQt5 and I'm not sure if there is a difference.  I couldn't get anything to work.

What I want to do is have the program update a QLabel after the user inputs text into it and saves it.  Right now I have the main window, with either a button or a selection from a drop down menu that will pop up a window with the ability to change setpoints.

Now what happens is the user can put in new data, but the code seems to still run and not wait for the user to make a change in the popup.  calling my updateSetpoints function before anything changes.

```
# popups the reactorSetpoints window to change the setpoints for
# the reactor.  This is where I am haiving troubles, the code
# continues before the user can input new setpoints
def reactorSetpoints(self):       
    exPopup = setpointsPopup(self)
    self.updateSetpoints()      

# just have it update the one value for now 
def updateSetpoints(self):
    self.pHUpperValue.setText(str(upper_pH))
```

A button calls reactorSetpoints(self) and popups a new window

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication,QLineEdit, QPushButton, QWidget, QDialog, QTextEdit, QLabel, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTime, QTimer, QRect
from PyQt5 import QtCore


from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

debug = True
setPointsChanged = False

versionNumber = 'V0.0.1'
currentState = 'Treatment'
currentCycTime = '2:15:42'
remaningCycTime = '5:44:18'

current_pH = 6.85
current_DO = 1.90
currentTemp = 24.9
lower_pH = 6.95
upper_pH = 7.20
lower_DO = 2.00


def openFile():
    if debug == True:
        print("Open File")  

def saveFile():
    if debug == True:
        print("Save File")

def saveFileAs():
    if debug == True:
        print("Save File As...")

def editSysParm():
    if debug == True:
        print("Edit system parameters")



def reactorParameters():
    if debug == True:
        print("Edit reactor parameters")

def pHCalibration():
    if debug == True:
        print("pH Calibration")

def dOCalibration():
    if debug == True:
        print("DO calibration")

def pumpCalibration():
    if debug == True:
        print("Pump calibrations")

def editpHSetpoints():
    pass



# sets up the setpoints popup window with either the option to save 
# new setpoints, or to quit
class setpointsPopup(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):      
        super().__init__(parent)        
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100,100,300,300)
        self.upH = QLabel('Upper pH: ',self)
        self.lpH = QLabel('Lower pH: ',self)
        self.lDO = QLabel('Lower DO: ',self)    

        self.upHE = QLineEdit(self) 
        self.lpHE = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lDOE = QLineEdit(self)

        self.upHE.setPlaceholderText(str(upper_pH))
        self.lpHE.setPlaceholderText(str(lower_pH))
        self.lDOE.setPlaceholderText(str(lower_DO))

        self.exitSetpoints = QPushButton('Exit', self)
        self.saveSetpoints = QPushButton('Save New Setpoints', self)

        self.upH.move(5,5)
        self.upHE.move(90,5)

        self.lpH.move(5,40)
        self.lpHE.move(90,40)

        self.lDO.move(5,75)
        self.lDOE.move(90,75)

        self.exitSetpoints.setGeometry(QRect(5,120,50,30))
        self.exitSetpoints.clicked.connect(self.destroy)
        self.saveSetpoints.setGeometry(QRect(60,120,150,30))
        self.saveSetpoints.clicked.connect(self.verifySetpoints)
        self.show()


    #verification will be put here to make sure the input is valid
    #but for now it will accept anything for ease of testing
    def verifySetpoints(self):
        global upper_pH     
        newUpH = self.upHE.text()                   
        upper_pH = float(newUpH)            
        print(newUpH)       


# Main window
class drawMenuBar(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):     
        super().__init__()
        self.topL = 20
        self.top = 40
        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 500
        self.title = ('Batch Reactor Controller ' + versionNumber)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.topL, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        exitAct = QAction('&Exit' , self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)    

        openAct = QAction('&Open', self)    
        openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAct.setStatusTip('Open File')
        openAct.triggered.connect(openFile)

        saveAsAct = QAction('&Save As..', self)
        saveAsAct.setShortcut('Shift+Ctrl+S')
        saveAsAct.setStatusTip('Save as new file')
        saveAsAct.triggered.connect(saveFileAs)

        saveAct = QAction('Save', self)
        saveAct.setStatusTip('Save')
        saveAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        saveAct.triggered.connect(saveFile)

        systemSetpointsAct = QAction('Preferences', self)
        systemSetpointsAct.setStatusTip('Edit system parameters')
        systemSetpointsAct.triggered.connect(editSysParm)

        reactorSetpointsAct = QAction('Reactor Setpoints', self)
        reactorSetpointsAct.setStatusTip('Edit reactor setpoints')
        reactorSetpointsAct.triggered.connect(self.reactorSetpoints)

        reactorParametersAct = QAction('Reactor Parameters', self)
        reactorParametersAct.setStatusTip('Edit batch reactor profiles')
        reactorParametersAct.triggered.connect(reactorParameters)       

        pHCalibrationAct = QAction('pH Calibration', self)
        pHCalibrationAct.setStatusTip('pH Calibration')
        pHCalibrationAct.triggered.connect(pHCalibration)

        dOCalibrationAct = QAction('DO Calibration', self)
        dOCalibrationAct.setStatusTip('Dissolved oxygen calibration')
        dOCalibrationAct.triggered.connect(dOCalibration)

        pumpCalibrationAct = QAction('Pump Calibrations', self)
        pumpCalibrationAct.setStatusTip('Pump Calibrations')
        pumpCalibrationAct.triggered.connect(pumpCalibration)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.statusBar()

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Edit')
        calibrationMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Calibration')       

        fileMenu.addAction(openAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAsAct)       
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

        calibrationMenu.addAction(pHCalibrationAct)
        calibrationMenu.addAction(dOCalibrationAct)
        calibrationMenu.addAction(pumpCalibrationAct)

        editMenu.addAction(systemSetpointsAct)
        editMenu.addAction(reactorSetpointsAct)         

        self.reactorTitle = QLabel('<b><u>Reactor 1 Status</u></b>', self)
        font = self.reactorTitle.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.reactorTitle.setFont(font)         
        self.reactorTitle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,30, 250, 45)) #(x, y, width, height)

        #pH Label
        self.pHLabel = QLabel('<span style="color:blue"><b>pH:</b></span>',self)
        font = self.pHLabel.font()      
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.pHLabel.setFont(font)
        self.pHLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,50,100,100))

        #displays current pH value
        self.currentpH = QLabel('<b>' + str(current_pH) + '</b>', self)
        font = self.currentpH.font()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.currentpH.setFont(font)
        self.currentpH.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60,50,100,100))     

        #display lowerpH Setpoint 
        self.pHLowerLabel = QLabel('Lower pH setpoint: ', self)
        font = self.pHLowerLabel.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pHLowerLabel.setFont(font)
        self.pHLowerLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 105, 115, 50))

        self.pHLowerValue = QLabel('{0:0.2f}'.format(lower_pH), self)
        font = self.pHLowerValue.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pHLowerValue.setFont(font)
        self.pHLowerValue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 105, 50, 50))

        #display upper pH setpoint
        self.pHUpperLabel = QLabel('Upper pH setpoint: ', self)
        font = self.pHUpperLabel.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pHUpperLabel.setFont(font)
        self.pHUpperLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 115, 50))

        self.pHUpperValue = QLabel('{0:0.2f}'.format(upper_pH), self)
        font = self.pHUpperValue.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pHUpperValue.setFont(font)
        self.pHUpperValue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 120, 50, 50))

        #pH button options
        self.pHToGraph = QPushButton('Graph pH', self)
        self.pHToGraph.move(10,160)
        self.pHToGraph.setToolTip('Show pH in live graph')
        self.pHToGraph.clicked.connect(self.displaypHGraph) 

        self.pHSetpointsButton = QPushButton('Update Setpoints', self)
        self.pHSetpointsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(115, 160, 150, 30))
        self.pHSetpointsButton.setToolTip('Edit pH Setpoints')
        self.pHSetpointsButton.clicked.connect(self.reactorSetpoints)   

        self.DOLabel = QLabel('<span style="color:blue"><b>DO:</b></span>',self)
        font = self.DOLabel.font()      
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.DOLabel.setFont(font)
        self.DOLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,175,100,100))

        self.currentDO = QLabel('<b>' + str(current_DO) + ' mg/L</b>', self)
        font = self.currentDO.font()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.currentDO.setFont(font)
        self.currentDO.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60,175,150,100))    

        self.DOLowerLabel = QLabel('Lower DO setpoint: ', self)
        font = self.DOLowerLabel.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.DOLowerLabel.setFont(font)
        self.DOLowerLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 225, 115, 50))

        self.DOLowerValue = QLabel('{0:0.2f}'.format(lower_DO) + ' mg/L', self)
        font = self.DOLowerValue.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.DOLowerValue.setFont(font)
        self.DOLowerValue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 225, 75, 50))

        self.DOToGraph = QPushButton('Graph DO', self)
        self.DOToGraph.move(10,260)
        self.DOToGraph.setToolTip('Show DO in live graph')
        self.DOToGraph.clicked.connect(self.displaypHGraph)

        self.tempLabel = QLabel('<span style="color:blue"><b>Temperature:</b></span>',self)
        font = self.tempLabel.font()        
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.tempLabel.setFont(font)
        self.tempLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,265,190,100))

        self.currentTemp = QLabel('<b>' + str(currentTemp) + '\u2103', self)
        font = self.currentTemp.font()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.currentTemp.setFont(font)
        self.currentTemp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(195,265,150,100)) 

        self.currentStatus = QLabel('<b><u>Other Parameters</u><b>', self)
        font = self.currentStatus.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.currentStatus.setFont(font)
        self.currentStatus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 325, 200, 50))          

        self.currentStatus = QLabel('Current Cycle: ' + '<b>' + currentState + '</b>', self)
        font = self.currentStatus.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.currentStatus.setFont(font)
        self.currentStatus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 340, 200, 50))  

        self.currentCycleTime = QLabel('Current Cycle Time (HH:MM:SS): ' + '<b>' + currentCycTime + '</b>', self)
        font = self.currentCycleTime.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.currentCycleTime.setFont(font)
        self.currentCycleTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 355, 250, 50))   

        self.remaningCycleTime = QLabel('Remaning Cycle Time (HH:MM:SS): ' + '<b>' + remaningCycTime + '</b>', self)
        font = self.remaningCycleTime.font()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.remaningCycleTime.setFont(font)
        self.remaningCycleTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 275, 50))      
        self.show()     


    # just a dummy graph that I got off a tutorial, it works for what
    # i need it to do for now
    def displaypHGraph(self):
        print("Display pH")
        self.m = LinePlot(self, width = 16, height = 9)
        self.m.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300,40,660,370))
        self.m.show()

    def displayDOGraph(self):
        pass

    # was playing with how to update labels here.  Just a counter
    # that counts up the value from the initial
    # this will eventually be replaced with sensor inputs
    def updatepH(self):
        global current_pH 
        global lower_pH
        global upper_pH
        current_pH = current_pH + 0.01  
        display_pH = '{0:0.2f}'.format(current_pH)
        if current_pH < lower_pH:
            self.currentpH.setText('<span style="color:red"><b>' + str(display_pH) + '</b></span>')         
        elif current_pH > upper_pH:
            self.currentpH.setText('<span style="color:red"><b>' + str(display_pH) + '</b></span>')
        else:
            self.currentpH.setText('<span style="color:black"><b>' + str(display_pH) + '<b></span>')

    # same thing as with the updatepH function except for DO
    def updateDO(self):
        global current_DO
        global lower_DO
        current_DO = current_DO + 0.01
        display_DO = '{0:0.2f}'.format(current_DO)
        if current_DO < lower_DO:
            self.currentDO.setText('<span style = "color:red"><b>' + str(display_DO) + ' mg/L</b></span>')
        else:
            self.currentDO.setText('<span style = "color:black"><b>' + str(display_DO)+ ' mg/L</b></span>')

    # popups the reactorSetpoints window to change the setpoints for
    # the reactor.  This is where I am haiving troubles, the code
    # continues before the user can input new setpoints
    def reactorSetpoints(self):       
        exPopup = setpointsPopup(self)
        self.updateSetpoints()      

    # just have it update the one value for now 
    def updateSetpoints(self):
        self.pHUpperValue.setText(str(upper_pH))




# dummy plot, was learning how to put a matplotlib 
# it works for now                      
class LinePlot(FigureCanvas): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=16, height=9, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        data = [6.89,6.90,6.91,6.92,6.93,6.92,6.96,6.99,7.12,7.14,6.98,6.93,7.01,6.90,7.11,7.21,7.13,6.99]
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data, 'r-')
        ax.set_title('pH')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        ax.set_ylabel('pH Value')
        self.draw()   

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = drawMenuBar()  
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(ex.updatepH)
    timer.timeout.connect(ex.updateDO)  
    timer.start(1000)
    ex.show()   

    sys.exit(app.exec_())       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so all of this works, except the only way I can get the label to update is to close out of the setpoints popup and reopen it.  What is a good way to update it upon exiting of the popup window?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call the reactorSetpoints function?

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is, a code that copies, executes and reproduces your error.

Comment: Figured it out.  At least it works, just needed to add the following line self.parent().updateSetpoints()